# curl command gives different output for a URL

Tags: http, url, curl

I am using curl to open a URL. If worked for few URLs. But for few its giving me an error report. When I open the same url in browser its working fine. The output of both the browser and curl command should be the same, but its not.What could be the reason?

```
$ curl 'http://server:port/ABC_Service/app'
<html><head><title>VMware vFabric tc Runtime 2.6.4.RELEASE/6.0.35.A.RELEASE - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 401 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>This request requires HTTP authentication ().</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>VMware vFabric tc Runtime 2.6.4.RELEASE/6.0.35.A.RELEASE</h3></body></html>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
$ curl 'http://server:port/ABC_Service/app'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
```

**Output in Browser (1st 2 lines):**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
- <appMetadata>
```

Comment: The response pretty clearly states a 401: This request requires HTTP authentication. Your browser must send credentials.

Answer (score 0):

The browser is just helpfully giving you an interactive view on the XML. Use *View Source* to see the actual response.

Answer (score -1):

A lot of websites try to detect if a browser can support XML / XSLT . If the user agent is something they know supports it, they send that which you see. If not, they send normal HTML (in your case, an error in HTML ).

You should try setting your user agent :

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_3 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8J2 Safari/6533.18.5" http://server:port/ABC_Service/app
```

You can find a list of user agent string from different devices / programs [here](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php)

Comment: Even this command to set user agent gave same html error output

Comment: do you have any cookie / login information on the web browser then ?

Comment: Nope..All the browsers are closed